# SCDF Aggregator Emits only the last record

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am currently experimenting for one of the usecase we have to aggregate multiple input meesages into one before it gets written to a file system. Towards this I am trying to use the aggregator module available here
https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/aggregator-processor-kafka/2.1.1.RELEASE/

My Environment is local SCDF/Kafka running on docker Dataflow 2.4.1.Release and Skipper 2.3.1.Release

the stream definition is simple as below

:inputTopic > aggregator > :outputTopic

In the aggregator properties am providing these property values.

```
release: size() == 5
group-timeout: 5000
correlation: headers.headerName
aggregation: T(org.springframework.util.StringUtils).collectionToDelimitedString(#this.![new String(payload)],'')
message-store-type: simple
```

There are two issues I have

1. Though i have given a release size of 5, and if there are say 10
   messages, i do not see my output topic to receive two messages
2. The output topic contains only the last message of an aggregated header and not concatenated values of this list.

Please suggest if there are any additional configurations that would help achieve an aggregated output.

One additional observation is that if i have a stream as

```
http | aggregator > :topic
```

The same aggregator config works fine and as desired. But the way we have it, the data is put into a topic via a processor using KStreams and not sure if there is a way in which the headers are generated and read using these default boot apps to a custom processor.

One additional observation during debug of aggregator is that, the correlationKey is obtained or compared via hashCode and not as string, not sure if its a bug or a feature. but this is what is causing the disruption of expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for an answer, the things i did to get around is to change the correlation to

```
new String[headers.headerName]
```

And explicitly configured the input value serializer to bytearrayserializer

But question i have from Spring team is if I do not have to touch aggregator, is there a property that i can set in my output producer properties in my Kstream app developed in 2.2.4 boot to emit headers as string instead of byte array?

i use following API to set headers

```
context.headers().add(key, value.getBytes())
```

I tried

```
producer.header-mode: to none/headers.
```

But my aggregator was still not aggregating and giving only last record. Only after changing the aggregator properties it worked. But i want to refrain from changing aggregator property as that stream is not owned by us and is legacy app working fine for other legacy streams.